# Execution Performance Issue with Similar Query

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-performance

I have been having some performance issues running a simple query on PostgreSQL on a table that has about 3 million rows with a join on a table that has about 120 rows.

If I run a query only on the larger table (with no filters), the results will return immediately, but with the join, results take up to 2 minutes to return the same results.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
    foi.fk_dim_product, count(1)
FROM evino_bi.fact_order_item AS foi
INNER JOIN dim_order_item_status AS dois
    ON dois.id_dim_order_item_status = foi.fk_dim_order_item_status
WHERE dois.is_reserved = '1'
GROUP BY foi.fk_dim_product;
```

Running the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFER), return the following:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=1379364.80..1379391.01 rows=2621 width=4) (actual time=84822.667..84822.863 rows=630 loops=1)
  Group Key: foi.fk_dim_product
  Buffers: shared hit=181461 read=1061877
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=6.38..1360785.99 rows=3715762 width=4) (actual time=0.180..84764.538 rows=96703 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (foi.fk_dim_order_item_status = dois.id_dim_order_item_status)
        Buffers: shared hit=181461 read=1061877
        ->  Seq Scan on fact_order_item foi  (cost=0.00..1301725.54 rows=5839054 width=8) (actual time=0.002..81484.109 rows=5837655 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=181458 read=1061877
        ->  Hash  (cost=5.06..5.06 rows=105 width=4) (actual time=0.053..0.053 rows=70 loops=1)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11kB
              Buffers: shared hit=3
              ->  Seq Scan on dim_order_item_status dois  (cost=0.00..5.06 rows=105 width=4) (actual time=0.005..0.038 rows=70 loops=1)
                    Filter: (is_reserved = 1)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 40
                    Buffers: shared hit=3
Planning time: 0.623 ms
Execution time: 84836.100 ms
```

The problem that puzzles me the most is that the following query runs in milliseconds and returns the same data:

```
SELECT
    foi.fk_dim_product, count(1)
FROM evino_bi.fact_order_item foi
INNER JOIN dim_order_item_status dois
  ON dois.id_dim_order_item_status = foi.fk_dim_order_item_status
WHERE dois.is_reserved || '' = '1'
GROUP BY 1
```

Here is the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFER) for the second statement:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=555597.70..555623.91 rows=2621 width=4) (actual time=249.523..249.673 rows=630 loops=1)
  Group Key: foi.fk_dim_product
  Buffers: shared hit=134117
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8172.60..555420.76 rows=35388 width=4) (actual time=2.971..219.564 rows=96860 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=134117
        ->  Seq Scan on dim_order_item_status dois  (cost=0.00..6.30 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.011..0.101 rows=70 loops=1)
              Filter: (((is_reserved)::text || ''::text) = '1'::text)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 40
              Buffers: shared hit=3
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on fact_order_item foi  (cost=8172.60..553329.08 rows=208538 width=8) (actual time=1.205..2.484 rows=1384 loops=70)
              Recheck Cond: (fk_dim_order_item_status = dois.id_dim_order_item_status)
              Heap Blocks: exact=132362
              Buffers: shared hit=134114
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on fact_order_item_fk_dim_order_item_status  (cost=0.00..8120.47 rows=208538 width=0) (actual time=0.467..0.467 rows=3903 loops=70)
                    Index Cond: (fk_dim_order_item_status = dois.id_dim_order_item_status)
                    Buffers: shared hit=1752
Planning time: 0.691 ms
Execution time: 249.917 ms
```

So, PostgreSQL is not planning my query adequately? Are there any performance tweaks that I can perform on my server to avoid the problems like on the first statement and helping PostgreSQL to plan better?

Also, why does the second statement runs absurdly faster?

**EDIT**

I updated the question adding the information requested.

**EDIT 2**

Here are the `\d` for both tables. I've hid some columns from the fact_order_item because the table has almost 150 columns, most are simple numeric values.

dim_order_item_status:

```
    Table "evino_bi.dim_order_item_status"
          Column          |          Type          |                                        Modifiers
--------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 id_dim_order_item_status | integer                | not null default nextval('dim_order_item_status_id_dim_order_item_status_seq'::regclass)
 src_id_order_item_status | integer                |
 name                     | character varying(100) |
 name_pt                  | character varying(100) |
 is_reserved              | smallint               |
 is_problem               | smallint               |
 payment_status           | character varying(15)  |
 macro_status             | character varying(100) |
 macro_status_pt          | character varying(100) |
 is_solid                 | smallint               |
Indexes:
    "dim_order_item_status_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id_dim_order_item_status)
    "src_id_order_item_status_idx" UNIQUE, btree (src_id_order_item_status)
```

fact_order_item:

```
                                                           Table "evino_bi.fact_order_item"
                  Column                  |            Type             |                                  Modifiers
------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 id_fact_order_item                       | integer                     | not null default nextval('fact_order_item_id_fact_order_item_seq'::regclass)
 src_id_order_item                        | integer                     |
 src_fk_order                             | integer                     |
 order_increment_id                       | character varying(50)       |
 order_type                               | character varying(50)       |
 is_instant_buy                           | smallint                    |
 nfe_number                               | integer                     |
 nfe_serie                                | integer                     |
 nfe_key                                  | character varying(50)       |
 nfe_created_at                           | integer                     |
 nfe_created_at_time                      | integer                     |
 nf_created_at_datetime                   | timestamp without time zone |
 fk_dim_city                              | integer                     |
 fk_dim_product                           | integer                     |
 fk_dim_product_bundle                    | integer                     |
 fk_dim_customer                          | integer                     |
 fk_dim_logistics_provider                | integer                     |
 fk_dim_channel_last_click                | integer                     |
 fk_dim_source_medium_last_click          | integer                     |
 fk_dim_content_last_click                | integer                     |
 fk_dim_campaign_last_click               | integer                     |
 fk_dim_channel_lead                      | integer                     |
 fk_dim_source_medium_lead                | integer                     |
 fk_dim_content_lead                      | integer                     |
 fk_dim_campaign_lead                     | integer                     |
 fk_dim_order_item_status                 | integer                     |
 fk_dim_payment_method                    | integer                     |
 fk_dim_subscription                      | integer                     |
 fk_dim_order_volume_status               | integer                     |
 fk_dim_order_volume_micro_status         | integer                     |
 fk_dim_sales_rule                        | integer                     |
 fk_dim_region                            | integer                     |
 platform                                 | character varying(40)       |
 created_at                               | integer                     |
 created_at_time                          | integer                     |
 created_at_datetime                      | timestamp without time zone |
 updated_at                               | integer                     |
 updated_at_time                          | integer                     |
 updated_at_datetime                      | timestamp without time zone |
 payment_confirmed_at                     | integer                     |
 payment_confirmed_at_time                | integer                     |
 payment_confirmed_at_datetime            | timestamp without time zone |
 cm2                                      | numeric(10,4)               |
 etl_updated_at                           | timestamp without time zone |
 variations                               | json                        |
Indexes:
    "fact_order_item_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id_fact_order_item)
    "fk_fact_order_item_src_id_order_item" UNIQUE, btree (src_id_order_item)
    "fact_order_item_fk_dim_campaign_last_click" btree (fk_dim_campaign_last_click)
    "fact_order_item_fk_dim_campaign_lead" btree (fk_dim_campaign_lead)
    "fact_order_item_fk_dim_channel_last_click" btree (fk_dim_channel_last_click)
    "fact_order_item_fk_dim_channel_lead" btree (fk_dim_channel_lead)
    "fact_order_item_fk_dim_city" btree (fk_dim_city)
    "fact_order_item_fk_dim_content_last_click" btree (fk_dim_content_last_click)
    "fact_order_item_fk_dim_content_lead" btree (fk_dim_content_lead)
    "fact_order_item_fk_dim_customer" btree (fk_dim_customer)
    "fact_order_item_fk_dim_logistics_provider" btree (fk_dim_logistics_provider)
    "fact_order_item_fk_dim_order_item_status" btree (fk_dim_order_item_status)
    "fact_order_item_fk_dim_order_volume_status" btree (fk_dim_order_volume_status)
    "fact_order_item_fk_dim_payment_method" btree (fk_dim_payment_method)
    "fact_order_item_fk_dim_product" btree (fk_dim_product)
    "fact_order_item_fk_dim_product_bundle" btree (fk_dim_product_bundle)
    "fact_order_item_fk_dim_region" btree (fk_dim_region)
    "fact_order_item_fk_dim_sales_rule" btree (fk_dim_sales_rule)
    "fact_order_item_fk_dim_source_medium_last_click" btree (fk_dim_source_medium_last_click)
    "fact_order_item_fk_dim_source_medium_lead" btree (fk_dim_source_medium_lead)
    "fact_order_item_fk_dim_subscription" btree (fk_dim_subscription)
    "fk_fact_order_item_created_at" btree (created_at)
    "fk_fact_order_item_delivered_at" btree (delivered_at)
    "fk_fact_order_item_nfe_number_id" btree (nfe_number)
    "fk_fact_order_item_order_increment_id" btree (order_increment_id)
    "fk_fact_order_item_payment_confirmed_at" btree (payment_confirmed_at)
    "fk_fact_order_item_ready_for_picking_at" btree (ready_for_picking_at)
    "fk_fact_order_item_shipped_at" btree (shipped_at)
    "fk_fact_order_item_src_fk_order" btree (src_fk_order)
    "fk_fact_order_item_updated_at" btree (updated_at)
```

**EDIT 3**

As requested, here are my DB specs:

```
Amazon RDS SSD db.m4.xlarge, PostgreSQL 9.5.2, Memory 16 GB, 4 cores.
```

These configs should be set with the default values as I haven't tweaked any of them:

```
cpu_tuple_cost: 0.01
random_page_cost: 4
shared_buffers: 4058056kB
work_mem: 64000kB
effective_cache_size: 8116112kB
MAINTENANCE_WORK_MEM: 259MB
```

Comment: Please post `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` as mentioned in https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. I updated the question with the information.

Comment: Show us the `CREATE TABLE` statements (and indexes). Or the output of `\d tablename` for both of them.

Comment: What happens if you compare `is_reserved` correctly with a number? `where dois.is_reserved = 1`

Comment: Well, if I remove the join and run `foi.fk_dim_order_item_status in (12,43,53 ...)` with the IDs that satisfy `dois.is_reserved = 1`, I receive the same slow results.

Answer (score 1):

there are many other discussions you will find for the same issue on the web. Just google it. I have attached few good reads for your own knowledge. there are different causes and different solutions related to Postgres DB engine configurations.

[hash join vs nested loop join](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAD1stZv-CsoBSpH3Oimu-OrhXPAf6ouA-pYLjbE6obgNpVNX8A@mail.gmail.com)

[Have Postgresql query planner use nested loop w/ indices over hash join](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66678/have-postgresql-query-planner-use-nested-loop-w-indices-over-hash-join)

[PostgreSQL query runs faster with index scan, but engine chooses hash join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643215/postgresql-query-runs-faster-with-index-scan-but-engine-chooses-hash-join)

A root problem I see is Postgres is choosing "Hash" join instead "Nested Loop" join and end up using Seq Scan with higher read cost. there are options using which you can either "disable HASH join" or "disable the Seq Scan" for a specific transaction but that will not be an ideal solution. An ideal solution is we want to write the query in a way so that Postgres pick up correct(most efficient) join type appropriate for the query. I would suggest to rewrite the query as below and lets us know how that works.

```
Select foi.fk_dim_product,Count(1)
From evino_bi.fact_order_item foi
inner join
(
    select id_dim_order_item_status
    From dim_order_item_status
    Where is_reserved = 1
) dois
on dois.id_dim_order_item_status = foi.fk_dim_order_item_status
group by foi.fk_dim_product;
```

If rewriting the query does not make Postgres switch to Nested Loop join type then my next best bet is checking the postgres version and follow the instruction to update configuration property "cpu_tuple_cost" along with other mentioned in one of the above-referenced discussion.

**EDIT:1**

Using the following index OP was able to get execution time **20-25 sec for cold cache and 6-8 sec for warm cache**.

```
Create Index Idx_order_item_status_AND_product ON fact_order_item   (fk_dim_order_item_status,fk_dim_product)
```

But, If we changes the order of column in above index and create it as following then execution order comes down to **3-4 sec for cold cache**.

```
Create Index Idx_order_item_status_AND_product ON fact_order_item   (fk_dim_product,fk_dim_order_item_status)
```

Comment: The query you provided executes on the same ~85 seconds. Running the query `select
    foi.fk_dim_product, count(1)
from evino_bi.fact_order_item foi
where foi.fk_dim_order_item_status in (5,8,19,...,83,84)
group by 1` also runs in ~85 seconds, so, I'm guessing the join might not be the problem

Comment: That means that this modification also not enough to hint Postgres Query Planner to use Nested Loop instead Hash Join. So as I mentioned in the answer, my next best suggestion is to check Postgres configurations as other dba/developers have mentioned in those articles. Did you get a chance to read them? Do you plan to try those setting update? if so Start with One at a time and check which one works: cpu_tuple_cost, random_page_cost.

Comment: Also first please update the post with current settings you may have for Postgres Version, OS Version, cpu_tuple_cost, random_page_cost, shared_buffers,work_mem,effective_cache_size,maintenance_work_mem ,

Comment: I just notice that table "fact_order_item" has two individual indexes for column "fk_dim_order_item_status" and "fk_dim_product". Before you try any other Postgres setting changes, can you create this index and try one or more version of a query that is taking more time: Create Index Idx_order_item_status_AND_product ON fact_order_item (fk_dim_order_item_status,fk_dim_product)

Comment: I can try adding that index, but I already have 30 indexes in my table. As it is a fast growing table, insert speed might start becoming an issue, would it not?

Comment: I noticed that you have many single column indexes. you are right in the sense that as the number of indexes increases write performance of the table will start getting slower. And that's why having many indexes on the table is also not good. we might have to look at the wide range of queries on this table and try to consolidate the indexes. So for an example if adding this new index works as we need, you might want to ask yourself why do I need the other two individual Indexes.

Comment: OK. I tried adding the dual column index to my table and it helped. But the execution time went from ~85 seconds to ~20. Working with HASH indexes in this case could be the solution?

Comment: can you explain bit more what you mean by "Working with HASH indexes in this case could be the solution?"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52882/discussion-between-anup-shah-and-leandro-barreto).

Answer (score 0):

You have two Seq Scans in that query.

1. Over `dim_order_item_status.is_reserved`
2. Another one over `foi.fk_dim_order_item_status`

Do either of these have indexes? If not, create the index and `VACUUM ANALYZE` the table.

A few other notes,

1. In PostgreSQL we don't use `1` for boolean.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE dim_order_item_status
     ALTER COLUMN is_reserved SET DATA TYPE bool;
   ```
2. Also `count(1)` is better written as `count(*)`

As for why the second query is faster, the concatenation is slowing it down so it pushes the index scan further down. My assumption is that your statistics are off for the rows returned by `fk_dim_order_item_status = dois.id_dim_order_item_status`. Normally, we could verify this if you ran `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` rather than just `EXPLAIN`. But anyway, run either `VACUUM ANALYZE` or `ANALYZE` on those tables if the problem persists after you create the indexes above.

If you come back we need:

1. `VACUUM ANALYZE` for all queries.
2. `\d dim_order_item_status`
3. `\d dim_order_item_foi`

Comment: Thanks for the notes, I'll keep these in mind. foi.fk_dim_order_item_status is indexed, is_reserved isn't. I execute VACUUM ANALYZE almost on a daily basis on my larger tables overnight, it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the faster plan, it underestimates the number of rows returned by the seq scan by a factor of 70, and it overestimates the number of rows returned by the bitmap scan by a factor of 50.  These two estimation errors mostly cancel out, leaving you with a good query.

The reason for the overestimation appears to be that items from one table which are is_reversed are preferentially rare in the other table.  PostgreSQL's planner has no way of knowing that.  There is no satisfying solution to this.  I'd take the approach you have already done--intentionally introduce one mis-estimate to make up for another one that can't be fixed.